# Duplicate sub-item in XML through PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is my First XML File-->
<FileHeader>
  <Item>
    <AddendA Test="1"/>
    <MICRDS Type="Regression"/>
    <ImageViewDetail>
      <ImageViewData Selected="Yes"/>
      <ImageDS ArrivalDate="04022018"/>
      <ImageViewAnalysis Status="Pending"/>
    </ImageViewDetail>
    <ImageViewDetail>
      <ImageViewData Selected="Yes"/>
      <ImageDS ArrivalDate="05022018"/>
      <ImageViewAnalysis Status="Complete"/>
    </ImageViewDetail>
    <ImageViewDetail>
      <ImageViewData Selected="No"/>
      <ImageDS ArrivalDate="05022018"/>
      <ImageViewAnalysis Status="In-Progress"/>
    </ImageViewDetail>
  </Item>
</FileHeader>
```

For the above XML I have written the following PowerShell script:

```bsh
$XML_Path = "D:\TEST_FOLDER\XML_FILES\Sample.xml"
# Create the XML File Tags
$Encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
$xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($XML_Path, $Encoding)
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteComment('This is my First XML File')
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('FileHeader')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()

# Create the Initial  Node
$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("AddendA")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("Test","1")

$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("MICRDS")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("Type","Regression")

$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageViewDetail")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item").AppendChild($CollectionNode)

$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageViewData")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item//ImageViewDetail").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("Selected","Yes")

$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageDS")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item//ImageViewDetail").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("ArrivalDate","04022018")

$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageViewAnalysis")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item//ImageViewDetail").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("Status","Pending")
$xmlDoc.Save($XML_Path)
```

So I am adding the following snippet into my code

```bsh
$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageViewDetail")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageViewData")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FileHeader//Item//ImageViewDetail").AppendChild($CollectionNode)
$CollectionNode.SetAttribute("Selected","Yes")
```

But it is not adding in the second tab it is adding it back in the first `<ImageViewDetail>` tag.

Also, one more question: I want to add one more attribute in the header section called `standalone="no"` which will look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>"
```

How to do it?

Comment: Does the node to which you want to add new child nodes have any distinguishing features? Attributes or child nodes by which it could be selected? Is it an empty node? In case of the latter you could select it via `$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//ImageViewDetail[not(./*)]')`.

Comment: Yeah, it has some distinguished feature for which I want to insert it a child item.

Comment: Then please provide a more complete XML sample, so that we can suggest a proper XPath query for selecting that particular node. [Edit] your question to do so.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how about the second question to change the header ?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have updated the XML as well

Comment: You removed the indication which node you want to modify. What are the criteria that determine which node should be selected? Last node? A node with a particular attribute in a child node?

Comment: Yes the last node , but even If I have n duplicate nodes then how to select any of the node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `<ImageViewDetail>` node can be selected like this:

```
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//ImageViewDetail[last()]')
```

For selecting other nodes you have to devise an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expression that matches the particular node you want to select.

The XML declaration can be changed like this:

```
$xmlDoc.ChildNodes[0].Value = 'version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"'
```